# Decorating several parent methods in child class

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator

I'm trying to decorate several methods of a parent class, while keeping the signatures and docstrings. This is normally possible with [decorator](https://github.com/micheles/decorator/blob/master/docs/documentation.md).

However, I need to pass "self" to the decorator because I need to check and change some attributes within the decorator, but I can't figure out how to do that.

```py
from decorator import decorator


class Parent:

    def do_something(self, this):
        print(f'something and {this}')

    def do_something_else(self, this):
        print(f'something else and {this}')


@decorator
def check_connection(method, self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.connected:
        # Connect here
        print('connected sucessfully')
        self.connected = True
    return method(*args, **kwargs)


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connected = False

        for attr_name in ['do_something', 'do_something_else']:
            setattr(self, attr_name, check_connection(getattr(super(), attr_name)))

a = Child()
a.do_something(this='this')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 30, in <module>
    a.do_something(this='this')
  File "***", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "***", line 15, in check_connection
    if not self.connected:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'connected'
```

Comment: if is not against nature I would try `Child.__bases__[0]` instead of `super`

Comment: I think you will fail into a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. To avoid that decorate parent to to give a subclass with decorated methods then use this

Comment: Thank you @cards. I tried with `Child.__bases__[0]` but get the same problem, "self" is not passed to the decorator.

Comment: Hi! Also if you fix the `self` problem, you will meet other problems! Your decorator `check_connection` is not well-formed... (actually you cannot expect to use it to decorate an instance method). As I mentioned in the previous comments... it is against nature because you introduce loops in the hierarchy tree. You should introduce a third party class with the task to decorate [which means redesign the problem!]

Comment: also `self.connected = True` is not clear what happen after decoration.  Would make sense to have `is_do_something_connected` and `is_do_something_else_connected`?

Comment: Basically before running several parent methods I want to check whether there is a connection and create one if this is not the case. The method will fail if there's no connection. I'm open for redesigning but not sure how.